# Permission read and execute, with end with -xr-x

Tags: permissions

I have run this command: `namei -nom /root/forngin/config.sock`

and i found following output:

```
 drwxr-xr-x root root     /
 drwx------ root root     root
 drwxr-xr-x root root     forngin
 srwxrwxrwx root www-data config.sock
```

I am trying to make permission of `config.sock` the file that ends with `drwxr-xr-x`

Currently my permission of `config.sock` file is `srwxrwxrwx`, now i want to make the permission like the

```
srwxr-xr-x root www-data config.sock
```

Can anyone help me in this case?

Comment: Please update question to address the following: What is the meaning of the file that ends with `drwxr-xr-x`? What have you tried?

Comment: Also add (to question), what Operating System are you using.

Answer (score 0):

Not all of those characters in the mode are permissions.

The first character is the file type: You can not change a files type. Therefore you can not change a socket (s) into a directory (d).

Comment: I just need it to end with xr-x, can i do it? how can i do it?

Comment: Have you tried `chmod`?

Comment: yes, i tried with 777 and 755 but not works

Comment: Define not work. Update question to: Show us what you did, and what happened.